# Trying to loop over all connected socket.io sockets in order to get the username associated with the socket but I'm having some troubles

Tags: javascript, socket.io

All my sockets have a property called username. I'm trying to loop over all sockets and console.log the username of that socket, however, when I try to do it, I console.log the id of that socket and I'm not sure why. This is how I'm looping it:

```
for (connectedSocket in io.sockets.connected) {
    console.log(connectedSocket)
}
```

This logs the id of the socket - fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC. I was expecting to see an object which would have a property called `username` which I could access like this `connectedSocket.username`.

When I console.log io.sockets.connected, I see this:

```
{
fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC: Socket {
    nsp: Namespace {
      name: '/',
      server: [Server],
      sockets: [Object],
      connected: [Circular],
      fns: [],
      ids: 0,
      rooms: [],
      flags: {},
      adapter: [Adapter],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1
    },
    server: Server {
      nsps: [Object],
      parentNsps: Map {},
      _path: '/socket.io',
      _serveClient: true,
      parser: [Object],
      encoder: Encoder {},
      _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
      _origins: '*:*',
      sockets: [Namespace],
      eio: [Server],
      httpServer: [Server],
      engine: [Server]
    },
    adapter: Adapter {
      nsp: [Namespace],
      rooms: [Object],
      sids: [Object],
      encoder: Encoder {}
    },
    id: 'fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC',
    client: Client {
      server: [Server],
      conn: [Socket],
      encoder: Encoder {},
      decoder: [Decoder],
      id: 'fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC',
      request: [IncomingMessage],
      onclose: [Function: bound ],
      ondata: [Function: bound ],
      onerror: [Function: bound ],
      ondecoded: [Function: bound ],
      sockets: [Object],
      nsps: [Object],
      connectBuffer: []
    },
    conn: Socket {
      id: 'fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC',
      server: [Server],
      upgrading: false,
      upgraded: true,
      readyState: 'open',
      writeBuffer: [],
      packetsFn: [],
      sentCallbackFn: [],
      cleanupFn: [Array],
      request: [IncomingMessage],
      remoteAddress: '::1',
      checkIntervalTimer: null,
      upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
      pingTimeoutTimer: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 30000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 3591,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: true,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 142,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 122
      },
      transport: [WebSocket],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3
    },
    rooms: { fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC: 'fnaADLbrz9wTiwhwAAAC' },
    acks: {},
    connected: true,
    disconnected: false,
    handshake: {
      headers: [Object],
      time: 'Fri May 01 2020 03:08:48 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
      address: '::1',
      xdomain: true,
      secure: false,
      issued: 1588291728124,
      url: '/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N7Da7Bu',
      query: [Object]
    },
    fns: [],
    flags: {},
    _rooms: [],
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      setSocketUsername: [Function],
      disconnect: [Function],
      message: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    username: 'hey'
  }
}
```

This is why I don't understand why I only see the id when I loop over the sockets.